# Rendering partial with remote: true if i have few same ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a problem with rendering data on my page through remote: true.
I have a comments and subcomments (comments to the comments). When I click "Comment" button under the second Post, a comment appears below the first because I have a few same ids "comment-list" in my loop. How I should fix this? P.S Sorry for my english :)

Here is how look my Post and Comments form:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<li class="post">
  ...
  <% if current_user == post.user %>
    <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</li>
<div id="comments-list">
  <%= render partial: 'post_comments/comments', locals: { post: post } %>
</div>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div id="comment-form">
    <%= render partial: 'post_comments/new_comment_form', locals: { post: post } %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is how looks my create.js.erb

```
$('#comments-list').html("<%= j (render partial: 'post_comments/comments', locals: { post: @post }) %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done in a similar situation is make your div IDs specific to each post:

```
<div id="comments-list-<%= @post.id.to_s %>">
```

and then in your jquery code specify the relevant post:

```
$('#comments-list-<%= @post.id.to_s %>').html("<%= j (render partial: 'post_comments/comments', locals: { post: @post }) %>");
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how i missed this

Answer (score 0):

1. Let create a wrapper specifying your `post`

   ```
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <div id="post_<%= post.id %>">
       <!-- Your current code here -->
     <div>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. Use `comments-list` as class instead (the same apply for `comment-form`)

   ```
   <div class="comments-list">
     <%= render partial: 'post_comments/comments', locals: { post: post } %>
   </div>
   ```
3. Finally your jquery selector in erb will be:

   ```
   $("#post_<%= @post.id %> .comments-list")
   ```